# Java 400 error but opens in browser

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am making a facebook software and for it i need to make a fql query to get friendlist. I use the below code

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM  user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =     me())&access_token="+access;
    url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    //add request header
    String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(responseCode);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }

    in.close();
```

But i always seem to get a 400 error.I have tried replace spaces by %20 but to no effect.
When i open the link in the browser, it opens good.

Comment: You're trying to send a POST request to this host. When trying to do it manually, I get a 400: Unsupported Post Request. When doing it in the browser, I assume you're sending a GET

Comment: You are right.WHy and how could i overlook that

Comment: If you want to fetch your friend list, i think you can use Graph Api :
me/friends

Comment: Yes that's a way too but i was doing this because i will be finding friends who are online using FQL and some other things so this will form a base to develop methods

Answer (score 1):

I feel ashamed.The solution is really the POST line which should be GET.

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM  user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 =     me())&access_token="+access;
url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
//add request header
String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1667.0 Safari/537.36";
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}

in.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer to your own question so others may find it useful. If you use chrome, I highly recommend an extension like Postman to send all your requests first and see what type of output your getting. Using a tool like Fiddler is helpful, too :)